# Can we download a complete infinite-scrollable webpage without actual scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, infinite-scroll

I have an infinite-scrollable webpage (downward scrolling only). I automated the scrolling but after a while the page becomes too large to scroll further. I manually deleted the read DIV blocks from the source code and it reduced the webpage size to normal but still the scrolling speed didn't improve. I could only scroll 1-2% of the webpage. Is there any way that I can fetch the full data on the client side of this webpage? My goal is to access certain elements using their classnames, after downloading the source code.

Comment: its better to parse ajax html instead of page's html.Find the way of fetching data on that page and follow it yourself.

Comment: I will try with AJAX but do you know why exactly it happens? If it is about the large DOM size then deleting the viewed DOM elements should make the scroll fast again. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax to fetch the data as you scroll:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp